# javascript, initiate animation if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, jquery-animate, checked

I would like to initiate an animation on a website but only i a certain checkbox is checked however I can't find how to do it. Can you guys help me?

For now I got this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(
                if (document.getElementById('#slide-1').checked){
                    function animation(){
                        $('.sl-art').fadeOut(1000);
                        $('#sl-art-1').fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                }
                else if (document.getElementById('#slide-2').checked){
                    function animation(){
                        $('.sl-art').fadeOut(1000);
                        $('#sl-art-2').fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                }
                else if (document.getElementById('#slide-3').checked){
                    function animation(){
                        $('.sl-art').fadeOut(1000);
                        $('#sl-art-3').fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                }
        );      
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sl-principal">
        <div id="sl-lucarne">
            <article class="sl-art" id="sl-art-1">
            <h2>Premier article</h2>
            <p>Premier slide</p>
            </article>

            <article class="sl-art" id="sl-art-2">
            <h2>Deuxième article</h2>
            <p>Deuxième slide</p>
            </article>

            <article class="sl-art" id="sl-art-3">
            <h2>Troisième Article</h2>
            <p>Troisième slide</p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <article class="checkbox">
        <label for="sl-art-1"><input type="radio" name="slide" value="slide-1" id="slide-1">Slide 1</input></label>
        <label for="sl-art-1"><input type="radio" name="slide" value="slide-2" id="slide-2">Slide 2</input></label>
        <label for="sl-art-1"><input type="radio" name="slide" value="slide-3" id="slide-3">Slide 3</input></label>
    </article>
</body>
```

As you can see I would like to fade to a certain slide depending on witch box is checked.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using [CSS transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) and [checked attribute selctor](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML and javascript have significant issues at the moment.

`<input>` is supposed to be self closing; `<label>` doesn't need a `for` attribute if it wraps an element (much less duplicate values for the `for` attributes); `$(document).ready()` accepts a function handle, closure, or arrow function;  declaring `function animation()` doesn't call it then and there; and `document.getElementById` requires the exact `id` value and not a CSS style selector (drop the `#` symbol).

All that aside and adding a change event listener to your radio, the code works.  You just have a lot of little problems with the markup and javascript.  All of it cleaned up, you have this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').on('change', function(){
        if (document.getElementById('slide-1').checked){
            $('.sl-art').fadeOut(1000);
            $('#sl-art-1').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('slide-2').checked){
            $('.sl-art').fadeOut(1000);
            $('#sl-art-2').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('slide-3').checked){
            $('.sl-art').fadeOut(1000);
            $('#sl-art-3').fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sl-principal">
  <div id="sl-lucarne">
      <article class="sl-art" id="sl-art-1">
      <h2>Premier article</h2>
      <p>Premier slide</p>
      </article>

      <article class="sl-art" id="sl-art-2">
      <h2>Deuxième article</h2>
      <p>Deuxième slide</p>
      </article>

      <article class="sl-art" id="sl-art-3">
      <h2>Troisième Article</h2>
      <p>Troisième slide</p>
      </article>
  </div>
</div>
<article class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="radio" name="slide" value="slide-1" id="slide-1">Slide 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="slide" value="slide-2" id="slide-2">Slide 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="slide" value="slide-3" id="slide-3">Slide 3</label>
</article>
```

Comment: You can make the selector more specific.  Maybe something like `$('article.checkbox input:radio')`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39771/)

HTML:

```
<div id="sl-principal">
    <div id="sl-lucarne">
        <article class="sl-art" id="sl-art-1">
        <h2>Premier article</h2>
        <p>Premier slide</p>
        </article>

        <article class="sl-art" id="sl-art-2">
        <h2>Deuxième article</h2>
        <p>Deuxième slide</p>
        </article>

        <article class="sl-art" id="sl-art-3">
        <h2>Troisième Article</h2>
        <p>Troisième slide</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
<article class="checkbox">
    <label for="sl-art-1"><input type="radio" class='slides' name="slide" data-key='1' value="slide-1" id="slide-1">Slide 1</input></label>
    <label for="sl-art-2"><input type="radio"  class='slides' name="slide" data-key='2' value="slide-2" id="slide-2">Slide 2</input></label>
    <label for="sl-art-3"><input type="radio"  class='slides' name="slide" data-key='3' value="slide-3" id="slide-3">Slide 3</input></label>
</article>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.slides').click(function(e){
     $('.sl-art').fadeOut(1000);
     $('#sl-art-'+parseInt(e.target.dataset.key)).fadeIn(1000);
   });
 });
```

Comment: Sorry but how is that supposed to help? I am trying to make it so that when the first checkbox is checked the first slide appears and when the second checkbox is checked the second slide appears and so on...

Comment: Do you need everything hidden by default and show a particular slide data when the particular slide number is clicked ?

Comment: no not nessesserally, I just want to be able to controll witch witch slide appears by sellecting a radio style input.